# Windows 10 x64: Unable to get PXE on Windbg

Tags: windows, debugging, winapi, memory-management, windbg

Can't understand how Windows Memory Manager works.
I look at the attached user process (`dbgview.exe`).
It is WOW64-process. At the specified address (`0x76560000`) there is `.text` section of the `kernel32.dll` module (also WOW64).
Why there is no PTE and other tables in the process page table pointing to those virtual address?

```
kd> db 76560000
00000000`76560000  8b ff 55 8b ec 51 56 57-33 f6 89 55 fc 56 68 80  ..U..QVW3..U.Vh.
<...>

kd> !pte 76560000
                                           VA 0000000076560000
PXE at FFFFF6FB7DBED000    PPE at FFFFF6FB7DA00008    PDE at FFFFF6FB40001D90    PTE at FFFFF680003B2B00
Unable to get PXE FFFFF6FB7DBED000

kd> db FFFFF680003B2B00 
fffff680`003b2b00  ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??-?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ???????????????
<...>
```

I know that pages will be allocated after first access (with page fault) have occured, but why there is no protype PTE too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, translate an arbitrary virtual address to physical using `!vtop` to see the `dirbase` of the process in the process of translation, or use `!process` to find the `dirbase` of the process:

```
lkd> .process /p fffffa8046a2e5f0
Implicit process is now fffffa80`46a2e5f0
lkd> .context 77fa90000
lkd> !vtop 0 13fe60000
Amd64VtoP: Virt 00000001`3fe60000, pagedir 7`7fa90000
Amd64VtoP: PML4E 7`7fa90000
Amd64VtoP: PDPE 1`c2e83020
Amd64VtoP: PDE 7`84e04ff8
Amd64VtoP: PTE 4`be585300
Amd64VtoP: Mapped phys 6`3efae000
Virtual address 13fe60000 translates to physical address 63efae000.
```

Then find that physical frame in the PFN database (in this case the physical page for PML4 (cr3 page aka. dirbase) is `77fa90` with full physical address `77fa90000`:

```
lkd> !pfn 77fa90
    PFN 0077FA90 at address FFFFFA80167EFB00
    flink       FFFFFA8046A2E5F0  blink / share count 00000005  pteaddress FFFFF6FB7DBEDF68
    reference count 0001    used entry count  0000      Cached    color 0   Priority 0
    restore pte 00000080  containing page        77FA90  Active     M
    Modified
```

The address `FFFFF6FB7DBED000` is therefore the virtual address of the PML4 page and `FFFFF6FB7DBEDF68` is the virtual address of the PML4E self reference entry (`1ed*8` = `f68`).

`FFFFF6FB7DBED000` = `1111111111111111111101101111101101111101101111101101000000000000`

`1111111111111111 111101101 111101101 111101101 111101101 000000000000`

The PML4 can only be at a virtual address where the PML4E, PDTPE, PDE and PTE index are the same, so there are actually `2^9` different combinations of that and windows 7 always selects `0x1ed` i.e. `111101101`. The reason for this is because the PML4 contains a PML4 that points to itself i.e. the physical frame of the PML4, so it will need to keep indexing to that same location at every level of the hierarchy.

The PML4, being a page table page, must reside in the kernel, and kernel addresses are high-canonical, i.e. prefixed with `1111111111111111`, and kernel addresses begin with `00001` through `11111` i.e. from `08` to `ff`

The range of possible addresses that a 64 bit OS that uses 8TiB for user address space can place it at is therefore `31*(2^4)` = 496 different possible locations and not actually `2^9`:

`1111111111111111 000010000 000010000 000010000 000010000 000000000000`

`1111111111111111 111111111 111111111 111111111 111111111 000000000000`

I.e. the first is `FFFF080402010000`, the second is `FFFF088442211000`, the last is `FFFFFFFFFFFFF000`.

[Note](https://blahcat.github.io/2020/06/15/playing_with_self_reference_pml4_entry/):

> Up until Windows 10 TH2, the magic index for the Self-Reference PML4 entry was `0x1ed` as mentioned above. But what about Windows 10 from 1607? Well Microsoft uped their game, as a constant battle for improving Windows security the index is randomized at boot-time, so `0x1ed` is now one of the 512 [sic. (496)] possible values (i.e. 9-bit index) that the Self-Reference entry index can have. And side effect, it also broke some of their own tools, like the `!pte2va` WinDbg command.

`0xFFFFF68000000000` is the address of the first PTE in the first page table page, so basically `MmPteBase`, except because on Windows 10 1607 the PML4E can be an other than `0x1ed`, the base is not always `0xFFFFF68000000000` as a result, and it uses a variable `nt!MmPteBase` to know instantly where the base of the page table page allocations begins. Previously, this symbol does not exist in `ntoskrnl.exe`, because it has a hardcoded base `0xFFFFF68000000000`. The address of the first and last page table page is going to be:

```
                        first   last
 *   pml4e_offset     : 0x1ed   0x1ed
 *   pdpe_offset      : 0x000   0x1ff
 *   pde_offset       : 0x000   0x1ff
 *   pte_offset       : 0x000   0x1ff
 *   offset           : 0x000   0x000
```

This gives `0xFFFFF68000000000` for the first and `0xFFFFF6FFFFFFF000` for the last page table page when the PML4E index is `0x1ed`. PDEs + PDPTEs + PML4Es + PTEs are assigned in this range.

Therefore, to be able to translate a virtual address to its PTE virtual address (and `!pte2va` is the reverse of this), you affix `111101101` to the start of the virtual address and then you truncate the last 12 bits (the page offset, which is no longer useful) and then you times it by 8 bytes (the PTE size) (i.e. add 3 zeroes to the end, which creates a new page offset from the last level index into the page that contains the PTEs times the size of a PTE structure). Concatenating the PML4E index to the start simply causes it to loop back one time such that you actually get the PTE rather than what the PTE points to. Concatenating it to the start is the same thing as adding it to `MmPteBase`.

Here is simple C++ code to do it:

```
// pte.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned long long int input = std::stoull(argv[1], nullptr, 16);
    long long int ptebase = 0xFFFFF68000000000;
    long long int pteaddress = ptebase + ((input >> 12) << 3);
    std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << pteaddress;
}
```

```
C:\> pte 13fe60000
0xfffff680009ff300
```

To get the PDE virtual address you have to affix it twice and then truncate the last 21 bits and then times by 8. This is how `!pte` is supposed to work, and is the opposite of `!pte2va`.

Similarly, PDEs + PDPTEs + PML4Es are assigned in the range:

```
                        first   last
 *   pml4e_offset     : 0x1ed   0x1ed
 *   pdpe_offset      : 0x1ed   0x1ed
 *   pde_offset       : 0x000   0x1ff
 *   pte_offset       : 0x000   0x1ff
 *   offset           : 0x000   0x000
```

Because when you get to `0x1ed` for the pdpte offset within the page table page range, all of a sudden, you are looping back in the PML4 once again, so you get the PDE.

If it says there is no PTE for an address within a virtual page for which the corresponding physical frame is shown to be part of the working set by VMMap, then you might be experiencing [my issue](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27286/kd-live-local-debugging-shows-same-output-for-pte-when-used-in-2-different-proc), where you need to use `.process /P` if you're doing live kernel debugging (local or remote) to explicitly tell the debugger that you want to translate user and kernel addresses in the context of the process and not the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that since Windows 10 Anniversary Update (1607, 10.0.14393) PML4 table had been randomized to mitigate kernel heap spraying.
It means that probably Page Table is **not** placed at `0xFFFFF6800000`.